# Garbled Intellij window in Windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea

My Intellij IDEA window gets garbled from time to time (see attached) I'm running the program 64-bit on a new Windows 10 laptop. The Intellij IDEA is version 2016.1.3 and build #IU-145.1617.

Can someone point me towards a fix? Many thanks

[image: Garbled Intellij]

Answer (score 0):

It may be that some exception is thrown internally in IntelliJ IDEA or a plugin. You can check the log to see if that is the case. Use the menu item `Help > Show Log in Explorer` to locate it.